# Font not rendering properly

Tags: bug, mathjax

I posted an answer  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177536/prove-that-the-cone-over-s1-is-homeomorphic-to-d2/177589#177589) on the main site concerning the cone over $S^1$. Now the notation I use for this is $CS^1$. On my answer, it looks as if the "$S^1$" next to the big $C$ has been raised up, is there some kind of bug with tex?

Thanks.

Comment: For me, it doesn't display with a raised $S^1$ (of course the $1$ is raised, but the $S$ appears in the same height as the $C$, as it should).

Comment: It displays correctly on my browsers as well (Safari/Firefox).

Comment: Could you please provide a screen shot and details on the system you use (browser/OS)? Also, did you try shift-refresh and/or emptying the cache before reporting here?

Comment: You should probably add a screenshot when suggesting a problem with rendering.

Comment: so... what's the status with this problem? why don't you follow up on it?